# How to make Power Automate Connectors work across organizations

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

I'm working on creating a Power Automate flow that will take an incoming email to an inbox and create an Azure DevOps Work Item.

The problem I'm having is that my corporate email and access to Power Automate is in one organization and the ADO environment is linked to a separate organization.

I can setup the email side of the flow just fine.  And it recognizes the ADO name in the ADO connector, but I get the following error:

Error code: '401', Message: 'TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource. Azure DevOps ActivityId: *** Details: TF400813: The user is not authorized to access this resource. clientRequestId: ***'. More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '***'.

I'm an administrator in the ADO environment so I know I have access to the ADO environment.  I think it's the fact that they exist in different organizations.  When I go to my account in O365 I can see that it shows the correct linked organization that the ADO environment belongs to.  But I'm not sure how to make them play nicely together in the Power Automate workflow.